# Matrix Multiplication in quadratic form and double product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, quadratic-forms, products

Given a quadratic form:

$$(FW+b)^T M (FW+b)$$

what i got is:
$$W^TF^TMFW+ W^TF^TMb+ b^TMFW + b^TMb$$

my professors sums the central terms in :

$$ 2W^TF^TMb $$
but how is this possible aren't they different?

Answer (score 1):

For typing convenience, let $\,a=FW,\:$ then the expansion becomes
$$\eqalign{
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
(a+b)^TM(a+b) &= a^TMa + \c{a^TMb + b^TMa} + b^TMb \\
}$$
Focus on the terms in red.

A scalar value can be thought of as a $(1\times 1)$ matrix, so it's technically symmetric.

The matrix $M$ is also symmetric, therefore
$${a^TMb = (a^TMb)^T = b^TM^Ta = b^TMa}$$